# .cls files, indexed in an ls-R File, are not found by pdflatex (macOS, MacTeX)

Tags: compiling, document-classes

I want to use a set of custom latex classes, so I copied the whole directory to `~/texmf` and execute `mktexlsr ~/texmf`.

Afterwards, the index file `~/texmf/ls-R` is created and the respective `.cls` files are listed in it.

But when running PdfLaTeX, the following error still occurs:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `tubsbook.cls' not found.
```

Why does PdfLaTeX does not find the files or the index file?

Comment: Where exactly did you put the `.cls`? It should be in `~/texmf/tex/latex/<folder>/<file>` and that folder doesn't need to be indexed. Is it found if you run `kpsewhere tubsbook.cls`?

Comment: @Skillmon `kpsewhich` not `kpsewhere`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer no, I meant `kpsewhere` as it is only about whether the file is found, `kpsewhich` would determine whether it's really used and no other instance of that file. Though technically, it is correct that `kpsewhich` would do the right thing in this case, too.

Comment: @Skillmon I don't have a kpsewhere.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer oh, those Windows users :) TeXLive on Linux has `kpsewhere` and `kpsewhich` (didn't know Windows doesn't have both).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer seems `kpsewhere` is a version of `kpsewhich` that iterates over each tree in `$TEXMF` separately.

Comment: You should ***never*** run `mktexlsr` on `~/texmf`. Anyway, MacTeX uses `~/Library/texmf` and this tree *must not* contain a `ls-R` file.

Comment: Argh, found the problem! I didn't keep the required directory structure and put the tubs directory directly in `~/Library/textmf`. Thanks!'

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed MacTeX, then the “home tree” is under

```
~/Library/texmf
```

However it's not sufficient to copy the file in that directory; rather create the path

```
~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/tubsbook
```

and copy the file in the last listed directory.

***Never*** run `mktexlsr ~/Library/texmf`. If you have by mistake created a `ls-R` file there, remove it.